# php file() not working with absolute url

Tags: php, file, url

I am using this code to write a line from a file to a page. It works when I write the php like this:

```
<?php
$f_contents = file("something.txt"); 
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$data = $line;
echo "$data";
?>
```

But not like this:

```
<?php
$f_contents = file("http://something.com/something.txt"); 
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$data = $line;
echo "$data";
?>
```

Why isn't it working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't want to use the URL. You want to use the full *file path*.

Comment: so how should i write the file path

Comment: `file("/var/user/your/httpdocs/something.txt")` or `../folder/file.xxx` - *Pick your flavour* ;-)

Comment: does that url work in a browser? is your PHP set to allow url_fopen?

Comment: I don't know, how can i check?

Comment: I am using 000webhost, file path `home/********/public_html/ads.txt` is not working, is this  how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use the URL. You want to use the full *file path*. This is the file path from the root directory on your server. I can't tell you what that is because I do not have access to your server but it would look something like this:

```
/root/path/to/wwwroot/something.txt
```

There are many ways to find out the path to a file. You can do it programmatically in PHP by placing a file in the same directory with the following contents:

```
<?=__DIR__ ?>
```

Then open it in a browser.

Your webhosting control panel should also be able to tell you. Same for an FTP client or SSH command line.

Comment: Btw i'm curious According to Php.net - file () "A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled". So if he enables allow_url_fopen in php_ini_system that should do it no?

Comment: Sure. But on shared hosting that's usually off and why force the server to go over the network on to the Internet and back to itself when the file sits right there on the hard drive?

Comment: U're right. Just wanted to be sure coz never passed url into file() - +1 - Bye <3

Comment: @JohnConde, i put your code in a php file, opened it in browser, it only shows: ____DIR____. What is it supposed to show?

Comment: Try using `<?php echo __DIR__; ?>` just in case your PHP version doesn't support short tags. And be sure it is only two underscores before and after DIR.